# Python selenium get location of an element

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have this [site](https://www.imobiliare.ro/inchirieri-apartamente/sibiu/hipodrom-4/apartament-de-inchiriat-3-camere-X84T100B2?lista=2361394) and I'm trying to obtain the **location** and **size** of an element based on this xpath `"//div[@class='titlu']"`

[image]

How you can see that is visible and has nothing special.

Now the problem I've faced is that when I'm doing the search for xpath like this 
`e = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` the **location** and **size**
of `e` are both 0

Also, for some reason, if I'm trying to get the text like this:
`e.text` is going to show me an empty string, and I need to get the actual text in this way `e.get_attribute("textContain")`

So do you have any idea how can I get the **location** and **size** of this element?

Comment: I understand now, what you want is `.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[1].location` notice `s` in elements and it select second element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two elements matching this `xpath`. `driver.find_element_by_xpath` returns the first one while you are looking for the second one. Use the ancestor `<div>` with `id` attribute for unique `xpath`

```
"//div[@id='content-detalii']//div[@class='titlu']"
```